# SciPy cdist Speed Difference

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scipy-spatial

I am curious as to why the following `cdist` differ so much in time even though they produce the same results:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

x = np.random.rand(10_000_000, 50)
y = np.random.rand(50)

result_1 = cdist(x, y[np.newaxis, :])

result_2 = cdist(x, y[np.newaxis, :], `minkowski`, p=2.)
```

The `result_1` is significantly faster than `result_2`.

Comment: Checking from [source, line 614](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.5.2/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L2403-L2784) you can see that the (default) euclidean distance calls `minkowski(u, v, p=2, w=w)`. Hence I am following this question.

Answer (score 3):

The C implementation of the Euclidean distance, [source lines 50-66](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.5.2/scipy/spatial/src/distance_impl.h#L63-L66), uses multiplication and a `sqrt()` call while the Minkowski distance, [source lines 381-391](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.5.2/scipy/spatial/src/distance_impl.h#L381-L391) is based on the much slower calls to the `pow()` function.

For reference, see discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351438/why-is-the-pow-function-slower-than-simple-operations) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417490/difference-between-sqrtx-and-powx-0-5) comparing `pow` to multiplication and `sqrt`.

So despite the appearance that the Euclidean norm just calls the Minkowski norm, [source line 614](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.5.2/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L2403-L2784), `cdist` actually [calls directly through](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.5.2/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L2759-L2772) to the C implementation where the code is different. The python `euclidean` function is not called in the actual execution.